# libcurl stuck in POLLIN timeouts

Tags: php, curl

A libcurl in my php code seems to be stuck indefinitely in a `poll` call. When I did an strace to the process id,

```
[user@server ~]$ sudo strace -p 19559
Process 19559 attached - interrupt to quit
poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000)  = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000)  = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout) 
poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000)  = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000)  = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000)  = 0 (Timeout)
```

This goes on indefinitely. The fd 7 is shown in /proc/19559/fd as

```
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Sep 19 19:44 7 -> socket:[335178801]
```

Can someone tell me why this is happening. What can I do to make libcurl exit when it timesout

Comment: +1 for using `strace`... if only more people did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`curl_setopt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) option `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` if set to nonzero value will render curl to fail on timeout.